# php error_log for every folder

Tags: php, apache

I have searched this for hours but haven't found working solution yet.

I have this setting in my php.ini

```
error_log = error_log
```

It should make separate error_log file in every folder if I'm right ?

But it does not. I also have this in the beginning of my script :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', 'error_log');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Still all my errors are logged in /var/log/apache2/error_log

How to make it to log errors in each folder where script is running ?

I'm running Ubuntu 1.04 with LAMP stack installed. 
php version is 7.2

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can set relative paths with something like...

`error_log = ../logs/error_log_name`

So if your index.php file is in /var/www/mysite/public/index.php then the log file will be in /var/www/mysite/logs/error_log_name

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this in my index.php : ini_set('error_log', '/var/www/html/myscript/error_log'); It didn't help. Errors are still going to apache error_log. I restarted apache, no help

Comment: That's an absolute path not a relative one, and I'm not sure you can change the error log with ini_set. Add phpinfo() to one of your scripts to check which php.ini the server is using and where it understands the error_log is. It might be that you are setting the config in the wrong file. Alternatively it might be that you have error_log definition twice .

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was permission issue, I forgot to do chown and chmod for this folder. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just discovered I changed php versions in my CPanel's MultiPHP manager from alt-php to ea-php. Reverting back to alt-php brought back the error_log files that had stopped working.